# How to know the path in System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)

Tags: vb.net-2010

```
strFilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)
strFilePath = str + "ApInterface_" + Format(Now.Date, "dd-MMM-yyyy").Replace("-", "") + "_" + Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss").Replace(":", "") + ".dat"
```

I have the above code snippet where it saves the file in .dat extension in the specified folder. The problem for me is about the path. When I specify the path something like **"D:\myfolder"**, the data will be exported and file will be opened but it wont get saved. If I specify the folder as **"D:\myfolder\"** it saves perfectly, why do I need `"\"` and the end?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx) instead of string concatenation. It will add the slashes as they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't your code be something like this:

```
strFilePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(HttpContext.Current.Request.ApplicationPath)
strFilePath = strFilePath + "ApInterface_" + Format(Now.Date, "dd-MMM-yyyy").Replace("-", "") + "_" + Format(Now, "HH:mm:ss").Replace(":", "") + ".dat"
```

As it stands, there is no explanation of what "str" holds.

Assuming the above is correct, the reason you need the "\" is because without it there are two distinctly different paths:

- D:\myfolderApInterface_01012001_010101.dat
- D:\myfolder\ApInterface_01012001_010101.dat

The first references a file called "myfolderApInterface_01012001_010101.dat" in the root directory of the "D" drive, while the second references a file called "ApInterface_01012001_010101.dat" in the "myfolder" directory of the "D" drive.

As someone else has mentioned, you can use Path.Combine which will work out whether a "\" is already present and add it in only if needed.

P.S. You may also want to consider using string.Format to build up your filename to improve readability

Comment: str is a string which reads value from text box( where i can specify the folder in which i can export my .dat files)

Comment: if thats the case then the first line of your code is redundant, however the above explanation stands. without the slash you're merging your directory and filename together into one filename